# Scheduling Hourly Background Tasks for Location Tracking and Uploading in a Version-Compatible Way

Tags: android, kotlin, background, version, android-workmanager

I'm working on a mobile app, and I need to schedule a background task to track the user's location every hour and upload it to a server. However, I'm facing a challenge in ensuring that this background process is compatible with both older and the latest app versions.

How can I implement a background task scheduler that triggers location tracking and uploading every hour? and What is the best approach for efficiently tracking a user's location in the background?